# Jetty 9 missing JSON

Tags: java, json, ajax, jetty

I am attempting to upgrade an application from Jetty 7 to Jetty 9 - specifically 9.4.9.  However, the jetty-util-9.4.9.v20180320.jar does not contain the JSON class.  According to the documentation at http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/9.4.9.v20180320/index.html?org/eclipse/jetty/util/ajax/JSON.html (if I am understanding it correctly) it should be there.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can find it in the `jetty-util-ajax` artifact.

See official [search.maven.org](http://search.maven.org/) results : http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.eclipse.jetty%22%20AND%20a%3A%22jetty-util-ajax%22

Tip, if you know the name of the class, just search for it on [search.maven.org](http://search.maven.org/)'s advanced search.

Example: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfc%3A%22org.eclipse.jetty.util.ajax.JSON%22

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  However, do you know why this jar was not included in the zip file from www.eclipse.org/jetty/download.html?    I thought that zip file would contain all jars for Jetty.